# bind a python function for a key/key sequence

Tags: python, readline

I want to make vi-style controls, like `i` to enter insertion mode, etc.

How do I do that with `readline`?
Or are there any analogs of `readline` that allow to bind a python function to a key/key sequence?

UPD: The main objective is to bind **python functions to keys**.
For example I have this function:

```
def myfunc():
    print("Output")
```

How do I make `p` key, for example execute the function above?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`readline.parse_and_bind`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#readline.parse_and_bind) with `set editing-mode vi` readline command.

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')
```

It will start in insert mode. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> will change to normal mode.

Comment: But how do I make keys call python functions?

Comment: @SPython, What do you mean? Are you making a editor?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm making a console with vi-style controls where you instead of typing command can just press few keys. Like abc to run command cde

Comment: @SPython, Try above code with followed by `raw_input()` (`input()` in Python 3.x).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) package:

#### Code:

```py
import keyboard

def myfunc():
    print("Output")

keyboard.add_hotkey('p', myfunc)

breakpoint() # for testing..
```

#### Example output

[image: example]

#### Short explanation

- The [`keyboard.add_hotkey`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.add_hotkey) takes

  - As first argument a string that describes the hotkey. For example `"p"`, `"ctrl+p"`, `"F3"`, etc.
  - As second argument, a function that is called when hotkey is used
  - As optional keyword argument `args`, iterable of arguments which are passed to the function.